# How to update user using SignupForm.php Model in YII2?

Tags: php, yii2

How to make update form using SignupForm.php in yii2 (`Advanced Template`) for helping users to update their data?

I don't want to use any external modules.

I have in SignupForm.php Model:

```
public function signup()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->first_name = $this->first_name;
        $user->last_name = $this->last_name;
        $user->sub_id = $this->sub_id;
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->status=10;
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        if ($user->save()) {
            return $user;
        }
    }

    return null;
}


public function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = User::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

I have SiteController.php Controller :

```
 public function actionProfile()
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }
    $id = Yii::$app->user->id;

    $model = SignupForm::findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->save();

        return $this->redirect(['/event/index']);
    } else {
        return $this->redirect(['user/view/?id='.$id]);

    }
}



public function actionSignup()
{
    $this->layout = 'loginlayout';
    $model = new SignupForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($user = $model->signup()) {
            if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                return $this->goHome();
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: basic or advanced template ?

Comment: Show your model and your related controller

Comment: I updated the question. @scaisEdge

Comment: Seems your actionProfile do (in part)  somethings similar. Please explain better your need.. so i can post the right solution (i hope)

Comment: I have posted a first  answer .. i hope is what you need

Comment: @scaisEdge. Scenario is :  User after login can enter his profile and can see his information thorugh the view which generated from user table but i want to change update action which already generated too  to get data from signup form model.

Comment: Ok i think the answer provided could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be this action is what you are looking for

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }
```

and for the password you need a function like this

```
    $id = Yii::$app->user->id;

    $model = SignupForm::findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $model->save();

        return $this->redirect(['/event/index']);
    } else {
        return $this->render('signup', [
                'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

For the passwrod you can't simply assign the value but you must update the value with a function like like setPassword with another variable

```
public function updatePassword($new_password) {
   $this->password_hash =   Yii::$app->security
          ->generatePasswordHash($new_password);
```

}

*Adapt the field name to your need*

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but i got that error   Getting write-only property: common\models\User::password

Comment: @scaisEgypt - Thank you man. This is best answer. but you need to call updatePassword in the actionUpdate.

Comment: Yes .. but   i leave somethings to do at you... so you can learn better... thanks ..